# Skype automatically blocks c# debug project

Tags: c#, skype, access-denied, skype4com

Since an update to Skype in the past few days - a c# project I have can no longer connect to Skype. Skype.Attach() is all is usually takes but now when I run through debugging the project, it fails to connect.

Skype is literally adding the project to a list of rejected apps and greying out the option to allow it. As I can find nothing on-line - does anyone here know the reason? I have 3 c# Skype projects and none can be run via Visual Studio to connect -they all get blocked now.
The odd thing is, if I run the project exe outside of VS - skype allows it.. So I can publish my app but not test the damn thing.

Any ideas please. My firewall is off and nothing else has been changed.

Comment: Did you try running Visual Studio with Admin privilegs?

Comment: I have tried but still it is added immediately to the blocked list of applications. I simply dont see why this would happen and it is Skype as its both my machines - at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Booya. 
Seems Skype will block a debug app for visual studio automatically unless you go to Properties > Debug > Uncheck Enable The Visual Studio Hosting Process.

Comment: I assume it's one of Skype's reserve engineering preventation methods